Синонимизировать [пароль] и [password]
Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

пароль (115 вопросов)
password (77 вопросов)

Описания у обеих нет.
Основная - пароль, т. к. она на русском и с ней больше вопросов.

Готово!
updating post history, 81 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 77 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 71 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'password': [password] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 186
tag remapping of [пароль] and [password] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym password -> пароль was approved!

